# calculate reads per million mapped read using R

Tags: r, bioconductor

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
   gene_id               A1      A2       A3     A4  length  Total
ENSMUSG00000000028       58      93       48     58   789     200                 
ENSMUSG00000000031       11      7        20     16   364     54                    
ENSMUSG00000000037       3       5         6     98   196     112                                       
ENSMUSG00000000058       66     93        69     71   436     299                                  
ENSMUSG00000000085       55     68        97     67   177     287", header=TRUE)
```

The table represents the read count in a gene in different samples (A1, A2..A4).
How can i calculate the reads per million mapped read (RPKM) for these raw read counts using R

RPKM = (number of reads in a gene * 1e6)/(Total*length)

```
out_put <-  read.table(text="
   gene_id               A1             A2             A3        A4  
ENSMUSG00000000028       367.5539      589.3536       304.1825    367.5539                   
ENSMUSG00000000031       559.6256      356.1254       1017.5010   814.0008                    
ENSMUSG00000000037       136.6618      227.7697       273.3236    4464.2857                                       
ENSMUSG00000000058       506.2747     713.3871        529.2872    544.6289                               
ENSMUSG00000000085       1082.6985     1338.6090      1909.4864   1318.9236", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Why did it not work?

Comment: @heroka.. im confused how to write the r script usibg this function

Comment: what function do you mean? Can you show some expected output? Looking at the data and formula you've given, the only thing you're missing is the number of reads in a gene (which I think is A1+A2+A3+A4?).

Comment: @Heroka, please find the expected output file.

Comment: I've provided a solution. If you're going to do more work in R: this is a very common problem with a multitude of possible solutions (apply-family, loops, reshaping, dplyr). I'd advise you to look up some tutorials in the matters, it will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: @Heroka, I new to R and i m very enthusiastic to dig more in to these types of solutions.

Comment: I've given you two examples, they might be a starting point.

Comment: @Heroka..Thank you. It was really helpful. it would be really nice if you could suggest any good tutorial  to start with. There are many available online though...

Comment: That's up to you. Look into dplyr and reshape2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this without writing lines or a loop is using melt and dcast:

```
library(reshape2)

m_df1 <- melt(df1, measure.vars=c("A1","A2","A3","A4"))
m_df1$RPKM <- with(m_df1, value*1e6 / (Total*length))

output <- dcast(gene_id~variable,value.var="RPKM",data=m_df1)
> output
             gene_id        A1        A2        A3        A4
1 ENSMUSG00000000028  367.5539  589.3536  304.1825  367.5539
2 ENSMUSG00000000031  559.6256  356.1254 1017.5010  814.0008
3 ENSMUSG00000000037  136.6618  227.7697  273.3236 4464.2857
4 ENSMUSG00000000058  506.2747  713.3871  529.2872  544.6289
5 ENSMUSG00000000085 1082.6985 1338.6090 1909.4864 1318.9236
```

A second way is to use sapply to create a matrix of estimates, which you can then either rename and add to your original data, or cbind to your gene_ids.

```
my_cols <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4")
RPKMs <- sapply(my_cols, function(x){
  df1[,x]*1e6/(df1$Total*df1$length)
}
)
output <- cbind(df1$gene_id,RPKMs)
```

Comment: Nice, +1. For a solution without reshaping, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this also without reshaping. Using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,indx:=.I][, lapply(.SD, function(x) (x * 1e6) / (Total * length)),
                      by=.(indx,gene_id,length,Total)]
```

this gives:

```
   indx            gene_id length Total        A1        A2        A3        A4
1:    1 ENSMUSG00000000028    789   200  367.5539  589.3536  304.1825  367.5539
2:    2 ENSMUSG00000000031    364    54  559.6256  356.1254 1017.5010  814.0008
3:    3 ENSMUSG00000000037    196   112  136.6618  227.7697  273.3236 4464.2857
4:    4 ENSMUSG00000000058    436   299  506.2747  713.3871  529.2872  544.6289
5:    5 ENSMUSG00000000085    177   287 1082.6985 1338.6090 1909.4864 1318.9236
```

Explanation:

- with `setDT(df1)` you convert the dataframe to a datatable
- with `[,indx:=.I]` you create a unique identifier for each row
- with `by=.(indx,gene_id,length,Total)` you determine the columns by which you want to group the data (these columns will not be transformed), by including the `indx` you make sure that each row is an unique group
- with `lapply(.SD, function(x) (x * 1e6) / (Total * length))` you apply the required calculation to each column which is not specified in the `by` statement

---

A similar solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

func <- function(x,y,z) (x * 1e6) / (y * z)

df1 %>% mutate(indx=seq(1,nrow(.))) %>% 
  group_by(indx,gene_id,length,Total) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(func(.,Total,length)))
```

wich gives:

```
   indx            gene_id length Total        A1        A2        A3        A4
  (int)             (fctr)  (int) (int)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1     1 ENSMUSG00000000028    789   200  367.5539  589.3536  304.1825  367.5539
2     2 ENSMUSG00000000031    364    54  559.6256  356.1254 1017.5010  814.0008
3     3 ENSMUSG00000000037    196   112  136.6618  227.7697  273.3236 4464.2857
4     4 ENSMUSG00000000058    436   299  506.2747  713.3871  529.2872  544.6289
5     5 ENSMUSG00000000085    177   287 1082.6985 1338.6090 1909.4864 1318.9236
```